# ZFS ACL's with Snapshots

Tags: windows, zfs, cifs, snapshot

Let's say I have a ZFS filesystem set up to share to users via CIFS, but ACLs are fine grained into the subfolders of the share to where certain users can't go into.  Let's also say I'm leveraging ZFS snapshots to enable Windows users to restore "Previous Versions".  Will the ACLs still keep certain users out of locations they're not supposed to browse into in the snapshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ACLs carry through to the snapshots, so users will have the same access to the snapshot views as they do to the live volume.